# How to enable multiple files upload for site template gallery

Tags: 2007, site-template, file-upload, form

I guess I have to add single line of code in "upload.aspx" page for this Site template gallery list, but I don't know where I can find this form.

I done it before for a list but can't remember how.

**In short I want to upload multiple site templates to gallery but there is no option for upload multiple documents**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be on the roll over menu "Upload multiple templates."

Comment: Nope, real problem was it doesn't show upload multiple files on any browser other then Internet Explorer and even for that you have to install activexControl. where as I was using "Google Chrome"

Comment: I didn't think about it not being in ie, but at least you could fix it, awesomeness.